# Session conflicts cakephp

Tags: session

i have this session configuration in my core.php file

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
    'name' => 'projet',
    'defaults' => 'database', // change 'php' to 'cake' or 'database'
    'timeout' => 4320,
    'cookieTimeout'=>10000,
'cookie' => 'my_app',


));
```

i have changed it bacause i have trouble with session:
in the same machine i want to login as an admin and as user with another (login an password of course) but in lose my session the last session ovverrite the first?
is there any solution please ,this my first site with cakephp ,thanks in advance.